# switch statement not load data in javascript

Tags: javascript

can we use in switch and logical &&
her the code first it work will and after few minutes it stop
and don't recognize the error and searched in google & youtube etc
don't found any sol

```
const url =
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/globaldothealth/monkeypox/main/latest.json";
async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
function getResults(data) {
  const results = {
    confirmed: 0,
    suspected: 0,
    England: 0,
  };
  data.forEach((person) => {
    switch (person.Status & person.Country) {
      case "confirmed":
        results.confirmed ++;
        break;
      case "suspected":
        results.suspected ++;
        break;
        case "England":
            results.England ++;
            break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  });
  return results;
}
(async function () {
  const data = await getData();
  const results = getResults(data);
  
  console.log(
    `${results.confirmed} confirmed cases\n${results.suspected} suspected cases.`
    
  );

  document.getElementById("vocs").innerHTML = results.confirmed;
  document.getElementById("voxsus").innerHTML = results.suspected;
  document.getElementById("gr").innerHTML = results.confirmed + results.suspected;

})();
```

Comment: `switch (person.Status & person.Country)` that's not using logical and, it's using bitwise and.

Comment: `person.Status & person.Country` will not return a string.

Answer (score 0):

An `if/else` statement is sufficient.

```js
data.forEach((person) => {
  if (person.Status && person.Country) {
    if (person.Status === 'confirmed') results.confirmed++;
    if (person.Status === 'suspected') results.suspected++;
    if (person.Country === 'England') results.England++;
  }
});
```